# AWS EC2 Django runserver problems with port 8000

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I am running an EC2 instance, and I am having a bit of problems.

As of right now, the website is functioning, but not properly.

Django is listening on 0.0.0.0:8000, and I have port 8000 exposed, and the ports are defined 8000:8000 by default. My EC2 security group has 8000 open for incoming, and I can telnet connect from my EC2.

However, when I type my domain name in, domain.com, it does not connect. It connects on domain.com:8000. But I obviously do not want to have that happen, the website should jump right to port 8000.

So in the ports setting of my django project, I remapped 80:8000 so that you connect from port 80 client side and that is mapped to port 8000 server side. It is working now, as domain.com connects.

However I plan on adding SSL certs and this is most likely not going to work, and this is just not good practice.

Are there ways to run multiple manage.py runserver and collectstatic commands as well? Should I be using nginx or is the manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 command enough? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use `runserver` in production. [Deploy your project properly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/), for example with Apache + mod_wsgi or Nginx + gunicorn.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use runserver in production. I would suggest using Nginx with uwsgi.

You can run multiple manage.py runserver commands provided that different ports are used. For example

```
python3 manage.py runserver 8001
python3 manage.py runserver 8002
python3 manage.py runserver 8003
```

You can also run multiple collectstatic commands. Although, you would presumably want to use different arguments for each command, for example

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic --settings=mysite.settings 
python3 manage.py collectstatic --settings=mysite.other_settings
```

Comment: Would you run collectstatic after the runserver command or before?

Comment: @DeltaModz hi, i have deployed my django app on EB and i am facing the same issue with apache that connection refused at 127.0.01:8000. Can you help me resolve?